# Regarding tagging questions asking for scriptural reference

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems confusion regarding using tags [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) and [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) and users have different opinions on definition of the tag. So, it would be better to clear the confusion and reach to some conclusion. I'm here trying to consider different cases with providing example questions and giving my opinion on using tags. You're welcome to provide your feedback.

---

Let's assume certain cases:

1. Questions asking about scriptures e.g.

   - [What are the Hindu scriptures which every Hindu should abide by?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54/277)
   - [What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/277)
   - [What are 16 shastras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7890/277)
   - [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/277)
   - [Which Shastras are more authoritative,the Smritis(Dharma Shastras) or the Puranas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16509/277)

---

2. Questions looking for location or source of stories and verse from scriptures which can be of following sub-types (I don't feel much difference between them though):

   This again can have two possibility (again there doesn't look much difference between 2.1 and 2.2 however may be worthy in some case)

   1. Verse
      (Either completely unknown)

      - [Which scripture is the source of the verse "janmana jayate shudrah.. " (everyone is born a shudra)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17882/277)
      - [What is the source of this (Kayena vacha...) text? or Where does it come from?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8978/277)
      - [Where is the mention of 'Shiva is Supreme Lord of Vishnu and Vishnu is Supreme Lord of Shiva'?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13597/277)

        Or locating from particular text
      - [Where does Yajurveda have "karpūragauraṁ karuṇāvatāraṁ....bhavaṁ bhavānīsahitaṁ namāmi" verse?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19882/277)

      <sub>Note that this is not about asking for particular verses e.g. "what is the sloka for worshiping Saraswati?"</sub>
   2. Story: questions finding story from text (Either completely unknown)

      - [Which scripture contains the story of Lord Venkateswara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27748/277)
      - [Which Hindu scripture contains the story of a desperate man hanging from a tree branch?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18241/277)

        Or locating from particular text
      - [Where in Mahabharata is found the story of Vashishta trying to commit suicide in Sutlej river?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23286/277)

      <sub>Note that this is not about knowing particular story e.g. "what is the story of sage Shakti?"</sub>

---

3. Questions asking scriptural reference for any theory or concept:

   - [Are there any references to Gravity in Hindu Scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9102/277)
   - [Are there Hindu scriptural references for "Simulation hypothesis" or the "theory of simulation"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20095/277)
   - [Reference to the 7 chakras in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2641/277)
   - [Does Any Hindu Texts Say Anything About The Evolution Of Consciousness?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2982/277)

   Questions asking for scriptural reference for custom/practice or saying:

   - [Which is the oldest scriptural reference for Diwali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21421/277)
   - [Do any scriptures say you're not allowed to read multiple Shakhas of a Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16837/277)
   - [Which Scriptures say that by chanting Lord's name during the time of one's death one can attain "Moksha"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16028/277)
   - [Can I please have a scriptural reference for Pitru Runa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14830/277)

   Note: This also includes questions like "Swami Vivekanada said something, is there any scriptural base of it?", "Is ...something.... mentioned in scripture"

   Part of these questions have been framed like looking for scriptural-reference are more or less similar to find story from scripture i.e can be classified as 2nd type:

   - [Do we have scriptural reference on Ashta Bhairava incarnations?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29027/277)
   - [Why Dattatreya is shown surrounded by 4 dogs and cow?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21780/277)
   - [Devshayani or Harishayani or Toli Ekadashi : Is there a Scriptural references?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14110/277)
   - [Are there any scriptural references of the trinity "Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh(Shiva)" as depicted in popular culture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20599/277)

---

4. Questions like "According to Vedas/Gita/Scripture/Hinduism........" or "As per scripture......."

   This type of question has several possibilities i) they can be looking for any advice/guidance for practice, ii) they can be looking for scriptural-reference, iii) they can be off-topic. So, we need to recognize the nature of question by reading body of question and then can take any necessary action viz. re-tagging, correcting title or casting close vote.

---

5. Questions allowed to identify deity from images e.g. [Does anyone know the name of this Hindu deity?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8163/277)

---

#### Tagging:

Let's recall the [purpose](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) of tag:

> A tag is a word or phrase **that describes the topic of the question**. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by **sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.**
>
> Tags can also be used to [help you identify questions that are interesting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) or relevant to you.

As mentioned in [this meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/277) [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) should be used for questions **about** scriptures. Though it can be used as broad tag for other cases also.

Now, let's talk about tagging different types of questions:

- [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) is the most suitable for **1st type** of questions.
- For **3rd type** of questions [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) would be inappropriate according to the tag excerpt. For these type of questions introducing a tag like [scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference) would be good idea.
- As mentioned if we consider 2nd and 3rd type similar than tagging them with **[scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference)** would work. For **2.1** [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) may be ok as broader tag, observing questions of type **2.2** using [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) may not be ok.
- For **5th type** of questions [image-identification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-identification) would server the purpose.

  Presently [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) has been introduced for image, verse and story identification. Now, the purpose of tag is to filter questions on particular topic. Here image, idols etc. *pictorial things* are different than *scriptural things* verse and story. Look at the couple of questions mentioned in [Are identification questions allowed in here?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/401/277), that is about allowing recognizing deities from images. So, using a tag like [image-identification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-identification) would server the purpose.
- For **4th type** of questions we need as mentioned, it needs to look over the nature of question and then to decide which tags would work.

Also note that sometimes for any kind of question, questions would like to prefer scriptural source (though other sources may also work) to be cited in answer For that purpose they specifies it in body of question and not necessarily required to add [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) or [scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference). However, If questioner is explicitly looking for only scriptural source to be cited then, it may be fine to add [scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference) in addition to specify in question.

By the way, there is one [reference-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag used for 14 questions so far. [reference-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) looks unclear, either that tag can be removed or made synonyms to [scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference).

Thanks

Comment: I have to scroll for solution and type of questions again and again. can you add solution and questions at same place?. For 2.1, scripture is not at all ok and the problem will be back again. It should be only used for texts only. For verse identification, we have ID tag don't we?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma He said "maybe" . Scriptural reference is fine IMO.

Comment: "can you add solution and questions at same place?" first I wanted to explain possible related types of questions and then go for tagging suggestion"

Comment: " pictorial things are different than scriptural things verse and story.Look at the couple of questions mentioned in Are identification questions allowed in here?, that is about allowing recognizing deities from images. " You take example of a post and example of 3 year old. There are only image identification questions then but later verse identification is also added. ID can be used for those questions also. Scriptural reference for that tag will become a meta tag. Scriptural reference is not the same as identifying source. Moreover, don't say wrong statement that I introduced the tag.

Comment: @Sarva yes ID can be used for those questions, but what will fit best, is what he told in his post.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It doesn't fit best. I thought this meta is for clearing up confusion. But limiting clear tags is not necessary. Image identification is not the right name for the tag. Many answers for image identification can be solved through google search. There's no problem with ID for verse identification. I saw no one complaining about that usage for those questions. Removing clear tags is unnecessary.

Comment: Well still specifying is better than keeping way too generic if you take my word. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma can you explain how scriptural-reference is a meta tag? Thanks

Comment: I-R is **not a topic** on the main site it is just a **user action**. That is reason enough to change it to Image-identification.   Scripture, war, king, death, birth, cow, mythology, sloka, women, sin etc etc etc are all topics which I-R is not. I am not sure why is it taking so much time to take such simple decision. @Pandya

Comment: Also I suspect thr will be sock voting involved both here (downvotes) and on the answer (upvotes) .. So, first one needs to remove those votes to get a clear picture. @Pandya

Comment: "It is user action" it's not at all the problem. There are other tags too which asks for "user action" like "book-recommendation", "translation-request"

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with splitting of [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) to [image-identification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-identification) and [scriptural-reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptural-reference) because the [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) is not broader tag and no harm in using for verse identification, story identification and image identification. [This post gives more clear info about it](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/are-identification-questions-allowed-in-here).

Finding source and scriptural reference are not same. Example for finding source is [what is the source of this famous verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/what-is-the-source-of-this-famous-verse) and for scriptural reference, [are there any references to gravity in hindu scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/are-there-any-references-to-gravity-in-hindu-scriptures)

I don't see any improvement in the changes you said, because the existing tags are totally fine and clear. If there is any confusion then it's a matter of writing the tag wiki clearer.

Comment: Thanks for providing a feedback. What do you think about existing [tag:reference-request] tag?

Comment: ID tag is very broad. If some user wants to filter verse questions or story questions from deity or image questions, how can h/she do if we include id tag for every question?

Comment: Yes @TheDestroyer that's true .. moreover the tag name itself does not  suggest **what** we are trying to identify... Reference-request also hv that drawback.. Image-identification is 100% clear and precise .. so also is scriptural-reference..

Comment: The broadest and most unclear tag I have ever seen on SE network is Scripture tag. What is this about? Are we able to know what is it about just by looking at the name? No. We have excerpt and wiki for that. If naming should be done on relation with Hinduism, we have many tags to delete. Parents, children, kings, s*x , all these are not saying what is the tag about.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Can you please tell me what will happen to Id tag if we implement what OP said?

Comment: @Pandya I agree with you for ref-rqst tag. It's unclear

Comment: It's the scripture tag which is broader than id-rqst @TheDestroyer identification is identification. No matter if it is verse or story or image. So i think those changes are not needed.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Scripture tag will be limited to only first kind of questions and description of Tag will be edited. Identification is broad as it could mean anything.

Comment: How it could mean anything when it falls only for those three? @TheDestroyer  Not all questions asks for identification

Comment: I am strongly in favour of creating the scripture-reference tag.